# C# Map Json Dictionary to nested class

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

I have a Dicionary with key values.

It can be dictionary or json string like below:

```json
[
    {
        "Key": "UserName",
        "Text": "Jack"
    },
    {
        "Key": "UserAge",
        "Text": 30
    },
    {
        "Key": "Address",
        "Text": "Address Location"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Id",
        "Text": 10
    }
]
```

I want to map above json to class below:

```cs
public class Record
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    [Description("Id")]
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Description("UserName")]
    [JsonProperty("UserName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Description("UserAge")]
    [JsonProperty("UserAge")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    [Description("Address")]
    [JsonProperty("Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to define the attribute with `Description` or `JsonProperty`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: So what type should the deserializer return? An `object[]`?

Comment: It should return a object `Record`. @yueyinqiu

Comment: You need to write your own custom JsonConverter, as Json does not know how to parse your object out of the box if the json structure is not similar to the objects structure. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#deserialize-inferred-types-to-object-properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 3 steps:

#### 1. Read the data into a collection a records

First define the record type:

```
record PropertyNameAndValue([property:JsonProperty("Key")]string Name, [property: JsonProperty("Text")] object Value);
```

I've used the `[property:JsonProperty(...)]` annotations to be able to use arbitrary names for the record's properties.

Let's read the json

```
var propertyNameAndValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PropertyNameAndValue[]>(json);
```

#### 2. Populate a flattened structure

Let's define a class with 4 properties:

```
class Model
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public long UserAge { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I've defined `Id` and `UserAge` as `long` instead of `int` since Json.NET will parse these numbers as `System.Int64`.

Let's populate with data

```
var model = new Model();
foreach (var property in propertyNameAndValues)
{
    typeof(Model).GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(model, property.Value);
}
```

#### 3. Define an AutoMapper rule

Since I'm not using AutoMapper on a daily basis I can't show you right now you how the mapping rule should look like. Later this week I might have enough time to play with it a bit :D

---

**UPDATE #1**

Thanks for the suggestion for [Lucian Bargaoanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811700/lucian-bargaoanu)
 here is the mapping:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    cfg.CreateMap<Record, Model>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Location.Address))
    .ForMember(d => d.UserAge, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.User.Age))
    .ForMember(d => d.UserName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.User.Name))
    .ReverseMap()
);
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks for the link, but I'm not sure how does it help to define a mapping between `Model` and `Result`.

Comment: It helps to map from `propertyNameAndValues` to `Model`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Ohhh, so you are saying the 2nd step could be done with AutoMapper.

Comment: For step 3, check https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html.

Comment: If you [name things right](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html), no `MapFrom`s are needed.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Well in that case I need to annotate most of the properties inside the `Model` class with `JsonProperty` attribute.

Comment: Whichever you prefer, but the `User` properties already have the right name.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Correct. I think it might make sense to leave a post with your proposed solution.